# Are reopen votes longer valid on Beta sites?

Tags: discussion, beta, closed-questions

Recently a question on the main site was reopened because of the reopen votes. I think on non-beta sites those reopen votes are only valid for a short time period. So it is more difficult to collect enough reopen votes.

Is this handled differently on beta sites? I have the feeling that reopen votes are valid longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a [change a few months back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594). Close and reopen votes now age more slowly. In particular, they stick around forever on low-view questions, the expiration timer starts ticking only when the question reaches 100 views. This is true across all sites, but the 100 view threshold captures more questions on low-traffic sites, so you'll see it happen more often on Travel.SE than on SO.